# How do I save a Juju service for later?

Tags: juju

When I'm finished using a Juju service for a period of time, how do I put it away so that I can bring it up in the same state?

Or,

Are Juju services meant to be stateless?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it is possible to save a juju VM or service. I think it is not designed for this behavior.

Here are two options, which may help you:

1.
If you need a some specific information, config-files or data which is in you juju VM, you can take a Snapshot of the VM (If you are allowd by you provider). Later you can restart the VM and access the data but you will not have the full environment if you destroyed it.

2.
Maybe easier is to create a second environment in your file: `~/.juju/environments.yaml` and let the first one running. This way you can use you first environment whenever you want. Set the second environment as default to access it directly with all you juju-commands.

The `environments.yaml` should look like this:

```
juju: environments
default: env3
environments:
 env1:
   ...environment settings...
 env2:
   ...environment settings...
 env3:
   ...environment settings...
```